# Get array of interested values from d3.nest() - D3JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I used d3.nest() to group my data into category.

```
d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d[indexCateCol]; })
  .entries(irisData);`
```

However, I'd like to know how can I make an array of value from the attribute that I am interested in.

```
 (3) [Object, Object, Object]
    0:Object
     key:"setosa"
     values:Array(50)
      0:Array(5)
       0:5.1
       1:3.5
       2:1.4
       3:0.2
       4:"setosa"
      length:5
     1:Array(5)
     2:Array(5)`
```

In other words, what I want to produce is arrays of column that I'm interested for each Species like [5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, ...] for "Sepal.Length" or from '0: 5.1' from each array in value.

I believe that I can write a loop to get those arrays but there are any more JavaScript-ish ways to do this.

Comment: I think you have to be more explicit showing the shape of your data to start with and the final shape of the data you wish it to become.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the array of values for each species (from what I understand based on the data you're showing), you can do :

```
var myNest = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d[indexCateCol]; })
  .entries(irisData);`

/* Get the values of setosa as an array of arrays*/
var arrSetosa = myNest.setosa.values;

/* Get the 1st value of the 3rd "column" */
var val = arrSetosa[2][0];
```